# Qt Get Notified by a signal emitted by a class member

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to reuse a library as a module in Qt, therefore, I want be make less modifications/patches to it as possible. The goal is to be notified by the `Q_EMIT` that is emitted by a class member. My example code is as follows:

**myclass.cpp**

```
public:
MyClass::MyClass(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    this->manager = new QOfonoManager(this);
}

public slots:
void MyClass::manager_available()
{
    qDebug() << "Manager available";
    QStringList modems = this->manager->modems();
    qDebug() << "Modems:" << modems << "-" ;
}

public:
void MyClass::test()
{
    QStringList modems = this->manager->modems(); //Starts getting available modems

    connect (this->manager,SIGNAL(availableChanged()),this,SLOT(manager_available()));

}
```

**qofonomanager.cpp**

```
void QOfonoManager::onGetModemsFinished(QDBusPendingCallWatcher* watcher)
{
    ......
    Q_EMIT availableChanged(true);

}


QOfonoManager::QOfonoManager(QObject *parent) :
    QObject(parent),
    d_ptr(new Private)
{
    .....
}
```

When I call `MyClass::test`, I expect the member class to signal `availableChanged` to `MyClass::available_changed`. What am I missing here, can I make use of the `Q_EMIT availableChanged(true)` without having to modify `QOfonoManager` code.

Any help is greately appreciated.

Comment: So your code in the `onGetModemsFinished` method gets executed but you don't see the output from you slot?

Comment: `QOfonoManager` is not written by me, but I want to be notified by its `Q_EMIT`. Because that indicated when modem search finished, so that's when I can get that information.

Comment: Move the `connect` in the constructor of `MyClass` after `this->manager = new QOfonoManager(this);`.

Comment: That I understand, but you can make sure that the code in `QOfonoManager` gets called, just use a debugger and check. It also possible that the code is done executing before the connection is established so the advice above, to move the connection, is a good start in investigating possible issues.

Comment: @ixSci, I think this is exactly the issue, i.e. the signal is emitted before the connection is established. That is why I think moving the `connect` where it belongs to should solve that.

Comment: I am gonna look into this very soon, thanks for all the answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the underlying issue is that your `connect` statement doesn't match the signal spec for `QOfonoManager::availableChanged`.  The signal is emitted with a `bool` parameter...

```
Q_EMIT availableChanged(true);
```

But your connect statement states it to be a signal with no parameters...

```
connect(this->manager, SIGNAL(availableChanged()), this, SLOT(manager_available()));
```

(Do you not get an error message at the console?  Something along the lines of `"QObject::connect: No such signal ..."` ?)

Changing the connect statement to the following should help to fix the problem...

```
connect(this->manager, SIGNAL(availableChanged(bool)), this, SLOT(manager_available()));
```

Or, better still, use the [new signal/slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) if you're using `Qt5`...

```
connect(this->manager, &QOfonoManager::availableChanged, this, &MyClass::manager_available);
```

In addition to the above you should heed the advice of @scopchanov & @ixSci regarding the placement of your `connect` statements.  It's vital that connections are established *before* signals are emitted otherwise the notifications will be missed.

Comment: @scopchanov Fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much @G.M. that fixed my problem. Also thanks to scopchanov for the suggestion, it was also worthy note.